# How to join 2 keras models into 1 with reshaping inbetween to train those models together as 1 model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 2 keras models. The 1-st is for encoding 256x192 images into 128-dimensional vectors. It's input shape is `(None, 192, 256, 1)` and output is `(None, 128)` (`None` is for batch size, it is always the first element of shape in all keras models). And the 2-nd model should compare 2 vectors from the 1-st model. So it's input shape is `(None, 256)` and output shape is `(None, 1)`.

I want to train those models with regular `fit` method. So I need to somehow concatenate them into one model to train it. The input shape of that model should probably be `(None, 2, 192, 256, 1)` (2 is for 2 images that should be compared), output shape - `(None, 1)`. And also I want to keep first 2 models to use them separately later.

Here's what I've tried:

```
class _layer_1(keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return tf.reshape(x, (x.shape[0] * x.shape[1],) + x.shape[2:])

class _layer_2(keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return tf.reshape(x, (x.shape[0] // 2, x.shape[1] * 2) + x.shape[2:])

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(2, 192, 256, 1)),
    _layer_1(),
    encoder_model,
    _layer_2(),
    comparator_model
])

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5), loss='mean_squared_error')
```

This should have manually reshaped tensors as I need. But it doesn't work. Here's the issue that appeared when I tried to use the `fit` method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "comparator_train.py", line 61, in <module>
    get_models()[2].fit(np.random.sample((30, 2, 192, 256, 1),), np.random.sample((30, 1),))
  File "comparator_train.py", line 54, in get_models
    comparator_model
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 587, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filecoqup163.py", line 12, in tf__call
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(x), (((ag__.ld(x).shape[0] * ag__.ld(x).shape[1]),) + ag__.ld(x).shape[2:])), None, fscope)
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "private_layer_1" (type _layer_1).

in user code:

    File "comparator_train.py", line 43, in call  *
        return tf.reshape(x, (x.shape[0] * x.shape[1],) + x.shape[2:])

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'


Call arguments received by layer "private_layer_1" (type _layer_1):
  • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2, 192, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
```

So how do I properly make that concatenated model?

Thanks for any help!

Update: Here are the models:

```
encoder_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(192, 256, 1)),
    keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=12, strides=2, padding='same', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=12, strides=3, padding='same', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(12, 12), strides=2, padding='same', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.8),
    keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(8, 11), strides=1, padding='valid', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.14),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='sigmoid')
])

comparator_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Comment: If you want two models to work together that you also want to keep separate, you need train the two separate models on their own data, then concatenate their outputs and train on it in a third model. If you don't want to keep them separate, you could do this all in one ensemble model. If you do the second option (depending on what you need), you'd need to use the Functional API, not Sequential API.

Comment: @Djinn , I want to use models separately, but train them together, because I don't know the intended output for the 1-st model. It's like an autoencoder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder ) which has 2 parts, encoder and decoder, and those parts may be used separately, but you have to train them together.

Comment: @Djinn , thanks for your suggestion about Functional API. I already thought about that. The problem is that batch size for the 1-st model will be twice as big as the batch size for the 2-nd model (because I need to encode 2 images with the 1-st model to compare them using 2-nd). And I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: You can't train them stacked but you can train them sequentially. Just use the output of the first with the additional input for the second. So the final dense layer's shape along with the input shape of whatever else you want to add should be the input of your second model.

Comment: @Djinn , there's nothing additional to pass into the second model. Only the output of the 1-st. And how should I train the 1-st model then? I don't know what should be at the output of the first model. My final goal is just to compare 2 images. It's like an autoencoder as I already explained. Nobody knows what should be at the output of the encoder (1-st model). So it's impossible to train encoder without decoder.

Comment: Your first model should have a set output shape unless it works with any input shape, then in that case, your second model would have similar input shape (None). Can you update your question with how you defined *ALL* of your models?

Comment: @Djinn , yes, it has set input shape. I can't just pass the output of the 1-st model into the 2-nd because I need to concatenate 2 outputs of the 1-st model (128-dimansional vectors) in one 256-demensional vector for the 2-nd model.

Comment: You can't train them in parallel, so you *can* pass the input of the first model to the second. You said it was using two inputs of the first? Just have the second model's input shape be `(2, 128)` or keep it `(256,)` and do any preprocessing on the data before passing to the second model.

Comment: @Djinn , can you provide an example please? And do you understand that all that preprocessing should be done inside of a trainable model? I can't just get the output of the 1-st model then do all the reshaping and then pass the result in the 2-nd model because then it would be impossible to train 1-st model. Concatenating 2 models into 1 is probably the only way of training the 1-st model.

Comment: You said you wanted the models to work separately. So you have to train them separately. Meaning you'll have the output shape and can do preprocessing within a model. Read more on the Functional API and complex topologies.

Comment: @Djinn , there is some misunderstanding probably. Do you agree that in autoencoders encoder and decoder are concatenated while training (regardless of the fact that they are used separately)? Then why isn't it possible to do the same thing with my models?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how these models are structured. Autoencoders still have an output. You said you wanted to have separate models, so you have to train them separately. Autoencoders are not separate models, but sub models that work together. They can't be separated. And they are not concatenated.

Comment: Even calling them submodels is a stretch. That's more of a GAN. If you're training them separately, the output shape isn't going to change. So you can do any preprocessing within the second model.

Comment: @Djinn , and my 2-nd model also has an output (which should also be the output of the "concatenated" model). My 1-st and 2-nd models should also be sub models like in an autoencoder. And they can be separated. For example the decoder of an autoencoder may be used separately to generate random images using random input (for face generation for example). the only thing that distinguishes my case from the autoencoder structure is that I need to use 2 outputs (not 1) of the 1-st model for the 2-nd.

Comment: The decoder in an autoencoder is trained on the data represented from the encoder, so it's not separate. Images produced from the decoder will have a representation from the domain of the encoder's input. It cannot be trained separately without keeping track of the outputs of the first model along with its inputs with the second model) essentially training them together.

Comment: And again, if you want to use two outputs from the first (because that's partly why you can't train them in parallel unless you did some scaler operations on the output), just have the second model's input shape be `(2, output_size_of_first_model)` or `(2*output_size_of_first_model,)`

Comment: @Djinn , yes. And that's the reason why it's impossible to train them separately. I am only talking about USING them separately (after training). My models should be trained and used exactly the same way! But in an autoencoder you can just call the input layer of the decoder on the output of the encoder. The same thing is not possible in my case because the batch size for the 1-st model should be twice as big as for the 2-nd model. That's the problem. Probably all the misunderstanding is because of my bad English (I'm from Russia).

Comment: The input of 2-nd model is already `(2*output_size_of_first_model,)` as you can see

Comment: Then that's all you have to do, but they can't be trained together. Because you're using different batch sizes on the models and you're performing preprocessing on the input of the second model by using it with other output of the first model. Autoencoders do not do that. The encoder has a set output shape and **no** non-scalar operations are performed on the output, so the output is fed directly to the decoder. Your model would require waiting for output before continuing, or else the batch size would decrease for the second model, which you can't change without training separately.

Comment: Consider modelA passed a dataset with one image. The output is one array of shape `(128,)`. modelB requires two outputs of modelA as input. How exactly can you train modelB off the single output from modelA from the single image dataset? If you want the input to be `(256,)`, modelA would need at least two input images, therefore modelB has no way of knowing how modelA will produce outputs. They can't be trained together. You could reshape modelA's output to `(2, 64)`, but it can't be `(256,)`.

Comment: There's no non-scalar preprocessing, what are you talking about? I am using only 2 outputs of the FIRST model as the input for the second. Here's how it works: I have 2 images that may be passed into 1-st model and I know what should be the result of the comparison of those images. So I need to join (concatenate) my models in such a way that those 2 images will be passed into the 1-st model to make 2 128-demansional vectors that will be joined in 1 256-dimensional vector (that "join" operation is all the preprocessing) that will be passed into the 2-nd model to get the final result.

Comment: Again, how does model2 work when model1 is only passed a single input when it's output shape is `(128,)`? You are performing non-scalar preprocessing by combining two outputs.

Comment: "If you want the input to be (256,), modelA would need at least two input images" yes and that's how I need it to work

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that combining two outputs is a non-scalar operation.

Comment: Just because you have the first model's input shape as `(2, (image_shape))`, doesn't mean the output is going to represent two outputs. It's still one. So you'd need 2x`(2, (image_shape))`, which means your second model is working with a different representation of data than the first. They can't be trained together.

Comment: Then what am I intended to do? Do you mean that it's completely impossible to train my models together? And how is it possible to train model1 separately in case I don't know what should be at the output of that model?

Comment: As I've said before, "Just use the output of the first with the additional input for the second. So the final dense layer's shape along with the input shape of whatever else you want to add should be the input of your second model."

Comment: model1 has only the shape of (image_shape), not (2, (image_shape)). An it has single output of (128,). So I need to somehow temporarily  turn it into model with (2, (input_shape)) input and (2, 128) or (256,) output.

Comment: "Do you mean that it's completely impossible to train my models together?" With what you're asking, yes. You can't do that.

Comment: "And how is it possible to train model1 separately in case I don't know what should be at the output of that model?" You already know the output shape...It's your choice.

Comment: I highly recommend you read more on tensorflow/keras models. This isn't really a teaching site.

Comment: "You already know the output shape...It's your choice" is there any option how to do that? Yes, I know all the shapes but I don't know the values. It's like the output of the encoder.

Comment: You set the output shape...It's your code...`keras.layers.Dense(units=128, ...)` Even encoders have their output shapes known. There's nothing random or variable about it. Again, I suggest you read more about these model libraries. You're trying to do something a bit advanced without knowing how to get the output shape from your own code.

Comment: "without knowing how to get the output shape from your own code" why are you thinking so? I know output shapes of my models.

Comment: "is there any option how to do that" it's your code. you can change it to whatever you want. "but I don't know the values" It's your code, you do know the values. If you don't know the values from your own code, you don't know what those values mean. Therefore, you need to do more reading.

Comment: Ok. You've probably misunderstood what values am I talking about. I'll search for a solution by myself.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution! It is to separate the batch of pairs of images into 2 batches of images (each of them having the original batch_size) so that i don't actually need to double the batch size. Then it is possible to apply `encoder_model` on each of those batches separately and join the outputs for the `comparator_model`. Here is the code that works:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2, 192, 256, 1)) # original batch of shape (None, 2, image_shape)
images1, images2 = tf.transpose(inputs, (1, 0, 2, 3, 4)) # (None, 2, image_shape) -> (2, None, image_shape) -> batch1=(None, image_shape), batch2=(None, image_shape)
v1, v2 = encoder_model(images1), encoder_model(images2) # applying 1-st model to get output1=(None, vector_size) and output2=(None, vector_size)
v = keras.layers.Reshape((256,),)(tf.transpose([v1, v2], (1, 0, 2))) # output1, output2 -> (2, None, vector_size) -> (None, 2, vector_size) -> (None, 2*vector_size)
outputs = comparator_model(v) # applying 2-nd model
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs) # combined model

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5), loss='mean_squared_error')
```

(Then I will train my new `model` with `model.fit` so that `encoder` and `comparator` models will be trained within that model)

Comment: So you still ended up training two separate models, the second having to wait for the first, and combining the first's outputs. Your current solution does not train them together. But a third model trained on their outputs. The very first comment I posted.

Comment: While the answer may be what you're looking for, it does not match the question. There is no concatenation. The models are not trained together. Your solution more resembles "How to sequentially train models"

Comment: @Djinn , the 3-rd model is the concatenation of the first 2 models. And I am only going to train that new model. May be "concatenate" is a wrong word for that ... It's a new word for me. I will update the title of my question. But still I don't see any fundamental difference between my model and the structure of an autoencoder.

Comment: An autoencoder does not have independently trained submodels. The decoder is directly trained on the output of the encoder and weights adjusted during training. Weights are not adjusted during training with independently trained models.

Comment: @Djinn , you probably do not understand how am I going to train my models. Because you literally have just described the way I am going to do that. The new `model` (model3) is made _only to train it._ `model` (model3) is a whole regular keras model, single python object. Of course weights of that model will be updated simultaneously (as simultaneously as it is possible) when I call `model.fit`. I am not going to use `encoder_model.fit` or `comparator_model.fit` because I don't know the actual `y_true` for the encoder. I will call `model.fit`. And that is the only purpose of `model` (model3).

Comment: Did you not say you wanted two separate models? "And also I want to keep first 2 models to use them separately later"  That's not what you have. Like, that's seriously the difference in what we're talking about.

Comment: Either you want to keep them separate and train sequentially (which is not what you have, since you can't split this model) or you want to train them together, in which case you can't separate them (which is your current answer). Using your words, you said you wanted them separate. Your current answer does not have separate models, you just enclosed certain layers within variables and passed that to your total sequential model. This is not what was originally asked. If you wanted, you could take all of them out and explicitly have it shown as one long sequential model. But this is not separate

Comment: Look at the answer I just posted. It's structurally the same as your answer. As you can see, you can't separate the models because they're trained together.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'separate models'. I already mentioned that I am going to train models together, not separately and not sequentially (if sequentially means using the output of one to train the other). I want to join my models only to train them together _as one model._ And this is what I asked. When I wrote "I want to keep first 2 models to use them separately later" I meant that I want to have `encoder_model` and `comparator_model` later in the code as different python objects to be able to call `encoder_model.predict(some_data)` or `comparator_model.predict(some_data)'.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially your accepted answer as a Functional API model. As you can see, what you have considered "separate models" are not separate models, but just layers inside a variable. If you want separate models, you'll need to independently train them. You have one model and it's not even an ensemble model.

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2, 192, 256, 1))
images1, images2 = tf.transpose(inputs, (1, 0, 2, 3, 4))
v1 = Input(shape=(192, 256, 1))(images1)
v1 = SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=12, strides=2, padding='same', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(v1)
v1 = BatchNormalization()(v1)
v1 = ...
v1 = Flatten()(v1),
v1 = Dense(units=128, activation='sigmoid')(v1)

v2 = Input(shape=(192, 256, 1))(images2)
v2 = ...
v2 = Dense(units=128, activation='sigmoid')(v2)

v = Reshape((256,),)(tf.transpose([v1, v2], (1, 0, 2)))
# your original question said concatenate so this is how that wouldve been
# it says join now but either way
# v = Concatenate(axis=-1)([v1, v2])

out = Dense(units=256, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(v)
out = Dense(units=256, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(out)
out = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(out)
```

Comment: Your code has one major difference from mine. It is that you have 2 models `v1` and `v2` with different sets of weights. But in my case `v1` and `v2` are only different outputs of one `encoder_model` which have only one set of weights.

Comment: But in general it does the same thing as mine.